# Bash: how to check and insert a string within a block in a file

Tags: bash, awk

Having a block in http.conf file like:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    ...
</IfModule>
```

Assuming using bash, how can I check if the following line

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

has been already added within the previous block,
and, if not, how can I add it at its bottom resulting in

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    ...
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

This block is just in the middle of the file:
the file content doesn't start or end with this block.

**EDITED:**
To make this harder, I realized I need a further check too: sorry to have missed it in my question. If the above line is already present within the mentioned block as a commented line as

```
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

(the char # might be the first char of the line or it might have some spaced before, as it might have or not some spaces after before the char A of AddHandler), I simply need to uncomment it, otherwise I have proceed to add it as described.

Comment: can you use awk? If so, please consider adding a tag for that, you'll get a good answer within the hour ;-) (not from me, I've got to go to a meeting). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i ':a;$!N;/^<IfModule mime_module>.*<\/IfModule>/{s/# *\(AddHandler application\/x-httpd-php \.php\)/\1/;/AddHandler application\/x-httpd-php \.php/!s/.*\n/&\n    AddHandler application\/x-httpd-php .php\n/;p;d};/^<IfModule mime_module>/ba;P;D' input.conf
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this one! I like to use sed, too. I had to correct your code in a couple of points:
1. protect slashes in AddHandler application/x-httpd-php
2. restrict action only to the block with 'mime_module' in the IfModule tag. The conf file contains others IfModule tags called differently as <IfModule cgid_module> and so on, and your code will add the string within each IfModule block, while I need to add it only to <IfModule mime_module> one.
3. I added a new line before adding the string, just to make it more visible.

Comment: So, for me, your final code would be:
sed -i ':a;$!N;/^<IfModule.*<\/IfModule/{/AddHandler application\/x-httpd-php \.php/!s/.*\n/&\n    AddHandler application\/x-httpd-php .php\n/;p;d};/^<IfModule mime_module/ba;P;D' httpd.conf

Comment: Thanks @LucaBorrione, funnily enough I just noticed the `/` in the `AddHandler` and corrected it. If the `IfModule`is needs to be more explicit then my new edit should correct that too.

Comment: Funny yes! I noticed after posting my comments that you've already edited your code by your own. To complete things I need a further step: could you please check the edited part of my question? Many thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
awk '
/mime_module/{
    flag=1
}

flag && /x-httpd-php/{
    has=1
}

flag && /<\/IfModule>/{
    flag = 0
    if(!has)
        print "AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php"
}
1' input.conf
```

Comment: I like you solution with awk, it's very clean! However I'm experiencing a problem using your code: I changed your code into awk '(program)' httpd.conf > /var/lock/httpd.temp.conf && mv /var/lock/httpd.temp.conf httpd.conf I created a temp folder and copied inside it my httpd.conf and a test.sh with your code in it, I execute it with 'bash test.sh' on httpd.conf which doesn't contain the line within the mentioned block and your code adds it correctly. Then if I remove the added line by editing httpd.conf and run again 'bash test.sh' your code does nothing: it doesn't add again the removed line

Comment: Anyhow I realized I need a further check, could you please check the edited part of my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following will replace anything inside the block "IfModule - /IfModule" with your text "AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php". So regardless if the comment (#) is found or if nothing is found the block will have the correct information.

Also it is IMPORTANT to note that this is an inline edit. The file you are wanting changed will be changed immediately upon running this script with NO BACKUP MADE. PRIOR TO TESTING ANYTHING PLEASE BACKUP YOUR FILE.

```
sed -i '/<\/IfModule>/,/<IfModule>/!s/    \.\.\..*/    \.\.\.\n    AddHandler application\/x-httpd-php .php/g' /yourfile
```

If you are working on OS X, you may want to try the following script instead

```
#!/bin/bash

CR="$(printf '\r')"

sed -i '' "/<\/IfModule>/,/<IfModule>/!s/    \.\.\..*/    \.\.\.${CR}    AddHandler application\/x-httpd-php .php/g" /yourfile
```

Example of Starting file:

```
<IfModule>
    ...
</IfModule>
<NOTHING TO CHANGE>
    ...
</NOTHING TO CHANGE>
<IfModule>
    ...
#   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
<NO CHANGE>
    ...
    NO CHANGE
</NO CHANGE>
```

Results:

```
<IfModule>
    ...
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
<NOTHING TO CHANGE>
    ...
</NOTHING TO CHANGE>
<IfModule>
    ...
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
<NO CHANGE>
    ...
    NO CHANGE
</NO CHANGE>
```